# How to implement proxy cache with persistent HTTP connection to server?

Tags: http, proxy

I have read in many blogs/books that maintaining a persistent connection between the proxy cache and server can provide a lot of benefits. So you have:

C ---- Proxy ------ S

Now, if the connection between the proxy and the server is persistent it can provide many benefits.

1) We save up on TCP 3-way handshake

2) We don't have to perform slow start. The congestion window will be large since many clients will be sending data through this TCP flow.

The only problem is how do I de-multiplex the replies I receive from the server in order to send them to the client? How do I find out which reply corresponds to which client?

Answer (score 1):

The latest nginx provides this feature. You may refer to the code. (upstream, proxy, upstream_keeplive..)

Comment: Can you post a link to the code or explain succinctly what it exactly does?

Comment: download http://nginx.org/en/download.html,  browse: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser#nginx/trunk/src/http/modules